# T/F Exercise in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

1. A set containing a single vector is linearly independent.
2. The set of vectors $\{v , kv\}$ is linearly dependent for every scalar $k$.
3. If $A$ has size $n\times n$ and $I$ (identity matrix), $A, A^2,\dots,A^{n^2}$  are distinct matrices, then $\{ I, A, A^2,\dots,A^{n^2}\}$ is linearly dependent.

My answers...

1. For $k*v=0$ , $k$ must be  zero. So i think this is true(does the set contain the zero vect0r??? Is the set with only zero vect0r dependent?? Then it will be false)
2. With $k=0$, the set is linearly independent so that is false.
3. Since $n\times n$ matrix has $n^2$ dimension, and the set $\{ I, A, A^2,\dots,A^{n^2}\}$ has $n^2+1$ elements, it must be linearly dependent. So that is true.

But with textbook's answer, I had wrong answers for all of this. Which one is my mistake?

Comment: Your answer for 3. is correct. It is even possible to show that $\{I,A,\dots A^n\}$ is linearly dependent (as a consequence of Cayley-Hamilton theorem), but it is not trivial at all.

Comment: Ohh thank you for your answer. My answer of 1 and 2 are wrong...now i know what i had mistake haha  anyway thankyou! I will study that theorem!

Answer (score 1):

1. By definition, a set of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ in a vector space over a field $F$ is linearly dependent if there exist $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n \in F$ such that $\alpha_i \neq 0$ for at least one $i$ and $\alpha_1 v_1 + \ldots + \alpha_n v_n = 0$. So if you begin with the set $\{0\}$ containing only the zero vector, is it linearly dependent?
2. If $k = 0$, we can write $(-k) \cdot v + 1 \cdot (kv) = 0$, where the second coefficient ($1$) is always nonzero. So with the exception of the case where $k = 1$ (where the set $\{v,kv\}$ is just $\{v\}$), we will have linear dependence. However, as Arnauld pointed out in the comments, in the case where $k = 1$ the set is just $\{v\}$, so in general the statement made in 2. is false.
3. If the question did, in fact, say that $I,A,A^2,\ldots,A^{n^2}$ are all distinct and $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix, then you are correct: the set $\{I,A,\ldots,A^{n^2}\}$ lies in an $n^2$-dimensional vector space but has order $n^2+1$. Therefore it must be linearly dependent.

**Edit:** So, to clarify, I agree with you on #3, and I believe on #2 that the book author didn't take into account $k = 1$, in which $\{kv,v\} = \{v\}$, and the statement is then false (unless $v = 0$). For $k \neq 1$, the set $\{kv,v\}$ will always be linearly dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. Is ok i know. But in 2, with k=0, kv=0*v so only trivial solution. Then isn't it independent?

Comment: What you say in 3 is that the answer is true. Right? Is the text book's answer worng??

Comment: I'd say 2. is false : if $k=1$, $\{v,kv\}=\{v,v\}=\{v\}$, so it can be a linearly independent set.

Comment: Thank you thank you i understanded your words!! I was wrong